# jwplayer can read only flv files?

Tags: flv, jwplayer

I have a doubt jwplayer can read only flv files or it can read every files

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> With over one million active users,
>   the JW Player™ is the Internet's most
>   popular and flexible open source media
>   player. It can support playback of any
>   format the Adobe Flash Player can
>   handle (FLV, MP4, MP3, AAC, JPG, PNG
>   and GIF).

- http://www.longtailvideo.com/

---

**EDIT**

If you need to deal with any other formats, you can run the conversions server side using ffmpeg

Reference

- http://www.ffmpeg.org/

Comment: hi jamie if a user upload MPEG or .DAT files what we have to do?